# How to research strightly a word in a loop?

Tags: search

I have text:

```
I want to select nest and not nestlé in this text. Only the word nest!
```

and a list :

```
myList = ["nest"]
```

```
function MyFunction()
  myList = ["nest"]
  for elem in MyList
        if search("=/elem", 'W') == 0
           exe '%s/'elem '\{0\}/REPLACE/g'
        endif
  endfor

endfunction
```

Can you help me, please, to get strightly the word `\<nest\>`?

Comment: The question is quite difficult to parse

Comment: What is “strightly”? That’s not an english word I’m familiar with... perhaps you meant strictly?

Comment: The `if search("=/elem", 'W') == 0` part doesn't make sense. It's literally searching for the exact string `=/elem` (no replacement for that variable) and why would you want to skip the next command if you find that anywhere in your text?

Answer (score 2):

You have a text (where? in a buffer? in a variable?) and you want replace words given in a list in the text with `REPLACE`?

TEXT:

```
I want to select nest and not nestlé in this text. Only the word nest!
```

LIST OF WORDS:

```
['nest', 'this']
```

RESULT:

```
I want to select REPLACE and not nestlé in REPLACE text. Only the word REPLACE!
```

Is this correct?

Assuming TEXT is in buffer on a first row:

```
for word in ['nest', 'this']
    " replace text in the first row
    exe printf('1s/\<%s\>/%s/g', word, 'REPLACE')
endfor
```

[image]

If text is in variable, use `substitute` function instead:

```
let s:text = 'I want to select nest and not nestlé in this text. Only the word nest!'

for word in ['nest', 'this']
    let s:text = substitute(s:text, '\<'.word.'\>', 'REPLACE', 'g')
endfor
```

[image]

Here of course you can be creative, for example use for loop to generate regex with all words combined and apply substitute only once or smth else.

**PS** if you want to substitute text in a whole buffer you can do following:

```
for word in ['nest', 'this']
    " replace text in the whole buffer
    exe printf('%%s/\<%s\>/%s/g', word, 'REPLACE')
endfor
```

NOTE: `%%` is to escape percent char, otherwise `printf` will substitute `%s` command with `word` which is not what you want.

Comment: instead of a loop, why not add the words to the `:s` command directly? something like this: `%s/\<nest\>\|\<this\>/FOO/g`, you can even do it in one line (although this is ugly): `exe '%s/'.join(map(list, '''\<''.v:val.''\>'''), '\|'). '/FOO/g'`

Comment: I didn't know what is really needed thus a simplified answer that might be what author wanted. And there is a note that it is possible to do for loop to generate a list of words. join and map also was in my mind but I am not sure author is ready for it.

Comment: Hey, how did you run the code block selected?

Comment: https://github.com/habamax/vim-evalvim

Answer (score -2):

I have found :

```
exe printf('1,'.line('$').'s/\<%s\>/%s/g', elem, 'REPLACE')
```

Comment: if you need to substitute text in a whole buffer use `:%s/word/toword/g`, see `:h :%`

Comment: Arsene: Instead of posting your own answer, you should just accept @MaximKim's answer. Please stop posting self-answers that are a rehash of what others have said, but often without enough explanation or context. If someone's answer fixed your problem, accept the answer. If you like it, upvote it. If you think it didn't get 100% right for some reason, leave a comment. (But understand that if answers don't get everything right, it might be your question that's too vague or under-specified, revisit and edit your question as needed to clarify it as much as possible.) Thanks!